# Using class inside a function

Tags: php

I'm trying to use my class inside a function called inside()
I have something like:

```
class MyClass{
  public function test(){ echo "test ok"; }
}    

$mc = new MyClass();

function inside(){
  global $mc;
  $mc->test();
}
```

But this doesn't work :(
I get:

**Fatal error:  Call to a member function test() on a non-object in ...**

One solution would be to pass the class $mc as an argument to the function inside() but I want something else :/

Any idea ?

Ty guys

Comment: simply test() is not a method

Comment: This code works fine, calling inside() outputs "test ok" as expected. What is the problem?

Comment: It's doesn't work for me, I got a Fatal error

Comment: Are you sure the code you run is the same as in the question?

Comment: Ty Wolfgang, actually it wasn't :). The problem was that I called the function before declaring $mc ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is to access a function residing inside a class you can define it as static

```
class MyClass {
  static function test() {
        echo "test ok";
    }
}
```

Then you don't have to use a global:

```
function inside() {
    MyClass::test();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `inside` function depends on the `MyClass` class, it should be passed in as a dependecy injection.

```
$mc = new MyClass;

function inside(MyClass $mc){
  $mc->test();
}
```

It looks like you need a refresher of the (Gang of Fours) injection design pattern, http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Comment: This is needs to be a comment since it is a recommendation. He says he doesn't want to do that and doing it with `global` will not prevent it from working.

Comment: Unfortunately, he doesnt know what he wants. He wants what is the best but doesnt realise why this is the best. Globals are evil and will get him into trouble later on!

Comment: I know it is not a nice way to use global, still this is not _answering_ the question.

Comment: I am of the opinion that if the questioner is making a mistake by asking the wrong question, the answer should point him in the right way. You are welcome to disagree and to downvote!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define test as `public function test(){...`.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake when copied/pasted :/ I correct my code (I still have the problem for the class)

Comment: @Kursion This works as expected here: http://ideone.com/zrIfsf . There must be another problem also.